# Asp.Net Web Api http Patch Issue

Tags: json, http, asp.net-web-api, patch

We have HTTP Patch in our Web API, but we are unable to recognize which fields are cleared with Patch.

Say, we have following Student class.

```
public class Student
{
 public int? Id { get; set; }
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
 public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

If user is requested to patch using following Json,

```
{
 "FirstName": "Test First Name"
 "Email": null
}
```

We have used FromBody to create following object from Json, but how we can identify that field is set to null in Json.

```
{
 "Id": null,
 "FirstName": "Test First Name",
 "LastName": null,
 "Email": null
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this without adding any new field(s) in class?